# InvalidOperationException on SqlConnection.Open

Tags: c#, sql

I'm designing a small IRC bot that will be used for a game in the chat.

The source, program and SQL connection details will never be available to the public, so I'm not worried about security.

My connection string is as follows:

```
"Server=sql.mydomain.com,3306;Database=sqldatabasename;User id=sqlusername;Password=sqlpassword;"
```

Needless to say, I have obfuscated the details here.
After googling around and finding http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/ I used it to generate this string:

```
"Data Source=sql.mydomain.com,3306;Initial Catalog=sqldatabasename;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sqlusername;Password=sqlpassword;"
```

In both instances, I am trying to open the connection with the following code:

```
using (var sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sql.Open();
    //SQL operations here
}
```

However I'm receiving an `InvalidOperationException` on `sql.Open()` every time.
I am absolutely certain that the details I'm putting into the connection string are correct, and based on what I found on google, the most likely cause of the Exception seems to be the connection string, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The message of the exception is simply

> Internal connection fatal error.

According to MSDN, `InvalidOperationException` on `SqlConnection.Open` can only mean 1 of 2 things:
Either no server or data source was provided in the connection string
or the connection is already open.

I'm assuming the first can also trigger if the server or data source is invalid somehow, as I've tried opening it with:

```
if (sql.State != ConnectionState.Open) sql.Open();
```

and I still receive the error.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the exception, e.g. the actual message of the exception.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise the exception's message was that relevant, added to OP

Comment: I understand it was 2 years ago, but anyway, are you sure you had SQL configured to listen for TCP connections? (by default it's off)

Answer (score 0):

Did some searching, and your string seems perfect. Even changed my string to be exactly yours and it worked here. Only thing i could find was this, But i do not know if it helps or bot(worth the try).

> "Data Source=tcp:sql.mydomain.com,3306;Initial Catalog=sqldatabasename;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sqlusername;Password=sqlpassword;"

Saw it on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) site but again, i do not know if it changes anything.

Hope it helps

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help. I also tried removing the port which caused a peculiar issue, the program would reach sql.Open(), and rather than throw an exception, crash or even close. It simply stopped. The program's window froze up, and the code just stopped continuing. I left it for a while and it threw an SqlException, stating that it couldn't find or access the server. This leads me to believe that adding the port after a comma in the Data Source is wrong.

Comment: Than it is probably a problem withing your datasource, if you can, try to create a dummy database on your computer. If it will work with (almost) the same connection string, you know for sure that the problem is within either: the datasource(sql.mydomain.com,3306) or the database itself, but i think that you datasource is "wrong"