# Getting an error when connecting a .NET API core to a SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here is my `appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=Servername;Database=iRegister;User Id=Usernae;Password=Mypassword!;Pooling=False"
  }
}
```

My Swagger Page when I try to test the connection:

> Error: response status is 500
> Response body
> Download

> Connection failed: Internal connection fatal error.

*I am able to connect to through using SQLCMD

My ConnectionTestController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ConnectionTestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ConnectionTestController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    return Ok("Connection successful.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500, $"Connection failed: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Visual Studio Output:

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: D:\user\Repos\API\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Threading.Channels.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Net.WebSockets.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\user\Repos\API\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\net8.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Data.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Transactions.Local.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Buffers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebApplication1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll
```

Appreciate any help

A good Connection Test

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Hi Dale! when I run the project with IIS Express and open Swagger I try to execute the ConnectionTestController api call. I get this output in Visual Studio: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll. It continues to run. The call is: curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:7092/api/ConnectionTest' \
  -H 'accept: */*' - It returns Connection failed: Internal connection fatal error.

Comment: You need to step through it with the debugger and see which line causes it, and hopefully get a clue as to why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528022/invalidoperationexception-on-sqlconnection-open

Comment: Are you trying to connect the legacy `System.Data.SqlClient` for .NET Framework to SQL Server 2022 by chance? Have you tried switching to the modern and supported `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead?

Comment: Thanks so much I had to shift to this using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient; Then make the global invariant false, in the project file! I have a successful connection! You can place your answer in solving if you want.